# Waiting for the response to load when Using Ajax Send

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I'm sending a request and receiving a response from the server using a javascript,

```
xxmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
myotherMethod();
```

what I want to do is, wait till the response is fully loaded for the next instructions to be executed, How can I achieve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: this will helps you http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `onreadystatechange`

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlhttp.readystate==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
myotherMethod();
}
}
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery you are able use async: false like this, Right now you are using core javascript so i don't have idea about it. but if you will try jQuery and any query related to this then ask me.

After add ***async: false*** then: after response **alert('b')** execute.. Other wise it will execute without response.

```
   jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'www.abc.com/1'
           async: false,
           success: function(returnHtml) {
               alert('a');
           }
               alert('b');
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `onreadystatechange`, `readyState` and `status`, try this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      // response is fully loaded, write your next instructions here
  }
};
```